# How to select info from the Action Output in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, select, mysql-workbench

I'm wondering if there's a way I can select the information from the action output panel that gives me the query results using the select statement? Is there a table where workbench keeps that info?

[image: workbench action output panel]

I need to insert into a table and get the "message" the workbench returns from the query, so I can debug later in case of error. How can I do that?

Comment: You should be able to use copy/paste.

Answer (score 0):

You right click on the result set

and get

To mark all entries, click where i made the red arrow

[image]